# Smooth Javascript mousemove similar to Cubism.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, cubism.js

I'm curious how Mike Bostock was able to create a vertical line that follows your mouse cursor in such a smooth way.  If you look here http://square.github.com/cubism/ , you can see what I'm talking about.

Take a look at a quick example I just made here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbfUq/

There are many times where the line in my example actually disappears. Is there some sort of position interpolation he is doing to create a smooth translation between two points that are not being recorded? If so, anyone know how to do something like that?

Comment: Did you try `transition-duration` in CSS? I found it works very well and it’s so much simpler! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acmsrzjx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing he's using a d3.js `transition`, see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions, to basically animate the line (and values) from the current line position to where the mouse cursor currently is. You can tell he isn't trying to just follow the mouse curse because if you move the cursor quickly you can see the line lag behind a bit, this is the animation time of the transition.

I put together a quick example of how this is done in d3.js at http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rt/4/. I didn't play around with it much so I'm sure you can get it even smoother, but this seemed pretty good.

```
var line = d3.select('#selection_line'),
    page = d3.select('#page_content'),
    x = 0;

page.on('mousemove', function() { x = d3.mouse(this)[0]; });

var update = function() { 
    line.transition()
        .duration(5)
        .ease('cubic-in-out')
          .style('left', x + 'px');
};

setInterval(update, 35);
```

Also keep in mind that `svg` elements tend to animate a lot more smoothly than `DOM` elements.  Here's a pure `svg` example ( http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rt/10/ ).

```
var graph = d3.select('#graph')
              .append('svg')
                  .attr('width', '100%')
                  .attr('height', 600);

var box = graph.append('rect')
               .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 100)')              
               .attr('width', '100%')
               .attr('height', 200)
               .attr('class', 'page_content');

var line = graph.append('line')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 50)') 
                .attr({'x1': 0, 'y1' : 0, 'x2': 0, 'y2': 300})
                .attr('class', 'selection_line');

var x = 0;

graph.on('mousemove', function () {
   x = d3.mouse(this)[0];         
});

var draw = function () {           
      line
        .transition()
        .duration(18)
        .attrTween('transform', d3.tween('translate(' + x + ', 50)', d3.interpolateString))
        .each('end', draw);        
};

draw();
```

Again, this is just a quick example but hopefully it gives you some ideas.

Comment: This works great! It doesn't cause the line to disappear. I don't know why this is true, but this is exactly what I was looking for! So are you saying that I should change the '#selection_line' to an SVG? This should be easy to do because the line will actually be following a mouse when hovered over and SVG graph.

Comment: Yes, the line should be an SVG line that you then apply a positional transform to using a similar transition to the one I used.  Since SVG has built in animation support it will be a lot smoother then moving a DOM element but repeatedly changing it's css values.

Comment: I have created a fiddle based on what you have showed me. I still feel like it is still not smooth for me. Any suggestions? here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AruC7/1/

Comment: I updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/AruC7/2/.  You were calling `draw` on `mousemove` which was constantly resetting the animation making it choppy. I also updated the duration, `17` or `18` seems to give the best results (about 30 fps).

Comment: I just want to clarify, I was calling draw on mouseover, which means it is only called while my mouse is hovering over the graph. At least that was my intention...

Comment: Right, `mouseover`.  Basically you are going to have an animation loop going all the time so the line will update whenever `mouseX` updates which will only happen if the mouse moves over the graph.  There is no need to also check for `mouseover`.

Comment: Ok well thank you so much for your help! I still have a lot to learn about D3

Comment: I actually have one more question about this .each('end', draw) method: how would I turn it off? Like, if I wanted the draw function to stop when the user clicks, how would that happen?

Comment: Add a check within the `draw()` function, something like `draw() { if (stop) return; ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

**I've made you a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zbfUq/37/

Essentially you have record the mouse position in the `onmousemove` event handler, but not actually move the line there straight away.

You then run a timer which checks every so often (every 10 milliseconds in my example), and moves the line closer to the mouse position.

In the `onmouseover` event, I set the line position to the mouse position, and set the timer going.

In the `onmouseout` event I clear the timer, and set the line position back to 0 (you could also hide the line).

The `updatepos` function first checks how far away the line is from the mouse position. If it is less than 1px away, it simply moves the line to the mouse position. If it is more than 1px away, it moves is closer at a speed proportional to the distance away it is (if the line is further from the mouse, it moves towards it quicker).

**Javascript code**

```
(function() {
    var selectline = document.getElementById('selection_line');
    var container = document.getElementById('page_content');
    var mouseX = 0;
    var lineX = 0;

    var linetimer;

    var updatepos = function () {
        var speed, distance;
        distance = Math.abs(mouseX - lineX);
        if (distance < 1) {
            lineX = mouseX;
        }
        else {
            speed = Math.round( distance / 10, 0 );
            speed = speed >= 1 ? speed : 1;
            lineX = (lineX < mouseX) ? lineX + speed : lineX - speed;
        }

        selectline.style.left = lineX + 'px';

    }

    $(container).on("mouseover", function(e) {
        lineX = mouseX;
        selectline.style.left = lineX + 'px';
        linetimer = setInterval(updatepos, 10);
    });

    $(container).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        console.log(mouseX);
    });

    $(container).on("mouseout", function(e) {
        clearTimeout(linetimer);
        lineX = 0;
        selectline.style.left = LineX + 'px';
    });
})();​
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for this code, very easy to read and understand your thought process. But, do you notice that the line will drop out (and hide) and some points? Mostly when you move too fast. I noticed that if you gradually work up to a fast mouse movement, then this doesn't happen... Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I actually added this in on purpose as I noticed that the cubism example you linked to exhibited this behaviour. To get rid of simply remove the `distance > 100` part from the `if` in the `updatepos` function (I wasn't really sure whether to include it or not, but I thought I would for completeness) Updated example without the jumpiness here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbfUq/39/

Comment: This example is still pretty jumpy for me, not nearly as smooth as the cubism.js example and the line often doesn't end up exactly under the cursor.  Is it smooth for others?

Comment: @Bill - I agree, still quite jumpy from me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that line is generated by using the cubism.rule, Check out view-source:http://bost.ocks.org/mike/cubism/intro/demo-stocks.html. What you need is the following:

d3.select("body").append("div") .attr("class", "rule") .call(context.rule());

This uses context.rule() to accomplish that, a d3/cubism function.

There's only one issue that the rule only covers the current screen. Once you scroll the screen up the rule (line) disappears.